# What app can I use to setup best screenshots for an App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore

Is there an ios, web or mac os app that will allow me to prepare better screenshots for App Store like this:

[image]

What do I mean?

- some iPhone in the image (the best one is iPhone X or iPad Pro for iPad screenshots)
- nice background selected by myself
- possibility to set title and subtitle or even without this (no problem with localizations)
- possibility to create different size for screenshots, according to requirements of App Store Connect.

Comment: Yes, I have tried https://apps.apple.com/pl/app/screenshot-maker-pro/id673545271 but it doesnt work like I need...

Comment: Asking for „best“ and „nice“ will lead to opinionated answers.

Answer (score 1):

Create the images yourself.

## Image Editing Software

There are numerous image editing applications available for macOS, including [Adobe Photoshop](https://www.photoshop.com) and Gus Mueller's [Acorn](https://flyingmeat.com/acorn/). Layout tools such as [Sketch](https://www.sketch.com) are also an option.

If you need free, [InkScape](https://inkscape.org) is available.

### Device Templates

Device templates are available [Facebook Design](https://facebook.design/devices) and [many other sites](https://mockuphone.com/device_list).

Comment: Hey, I dont looking for image editing tools;)

Comment: It will be faster to create the images yourself, than find the "perfect" application. Many of the tools mentioned are scriptable and have templates specifically aimed at your needs.

Comment: Hello, I will remove the question if you remove the answer. Can we do it like this?;)

Comment: Your question and the answer have value for others – even with the down votes. There is no need to remove either. Feel free to edit your question to attract less opinion based answers, or ask for help on https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/